# Replace Text with Other Values in Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm successfully returning an array that maps out the ideal path between nodes on a network.

The result is (for a sample i,j pair) something like this.

```
1>34>65>23>742
```

Now I'd like to replace the numbers with the name of the city it represents, like San Francisco (SFO), so it would read something like

```
SFO>LAX>DFW>JFK
```

I've tried using the replace functions, but to no success.

```
    for z in range(len(names)):
        nextstop = [sub.replace(z, names[z]) for sub in nextstop]
```

Where `names` contains the names of the airports, in the same order/index as the numbers.

Thanks!

where the numbers represent

Comment: I don't know the numbers representing cities but i suggest to use **re.sub** method from **re** module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
cities = [names[int(x)] for x in "1>34>65>23>742".split(">")]
">".join(cities)
```

What's happening is that `"1>34>65>23>742".split(">")` gives you a list of the numbers as strings. Then the list comprehension `[names[int(x)] for x in "1>34>65>23>742".split(">")]` takes each of those strings, turns them into numbers and looks them up in `names`. So now we have a list of numbers. Finally `"<".join`  turns them back into your string format again.